# How to use Theme and Props in MUI-5 styled engine

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using `@mui/styled-engine-sc` to access `styled` from `mui 5`. As I want to be able to access other styled components as selectors ([components selector API](https://mui.com/system/styled/#how-to-use-components-selector-api)).

Given the snippet in MUI:

```
const Child = styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

const Parent = styled.div`
  ${Child} {
    color: green;
  }
`;
```

How can I access mui theme and other props optionally using the styled template.

I know it is accessible with `styled` imported with `@mui/system` but that would not give me access to other styled component selectors (if I'm not wrong).

I tried the following but without any luck as I could not get any accessible variable from typescript:

```
const Child = styled('div')({theme}) => `
  color: red;
`;

const Child = styled('div') `
  color: ${({theme}) => theme. };
`;
```

Any suggestion or reference on that I'm missing? much appreciated.